# Alternative for require.main.filename using ES6 Modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

how do I get the path url of the main file using ES6?
like in nodejs we have `require.main.filename` does import have something like that?

Comment: What's your definition of "main file"?

Comment: If by main file, you mean the root file that nodejs executed to start this nodejs process, then you could use `process.argv[1]`.  If the command line passed to node did not have a file extension on the file it was passed, then `process.argv[1]` also won't have that file extension either.

Answer (score 0):

## Dependency Injection

[@jfriend00 suggested that you could use `process.argv[1]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72153742/alternative-for-require-main-filename-using-es6-modules#comment127487201_72153742), but mentioned that it has a limitation that if you don't enter the extension when running `node`, `process.argv[1]` won't have it either

I believe you can resolve that second problem with `require.resolve`, but you need to result to dependency injection from a CommonJS script, as ES6 modules don't have `require` defined.

### Result of either solution:

```bash
> node main

.../path/to/main.js
```

### Inject `require.resolve()`

##### main.js:

```js
import( "module.mjs" )
  .then( r => r.default( require.resolve ) )
```

or

```js
async ()=>{
  await import( "module.mjs" )
    .default( require.resolve )
}
```

##### module.mjs

```js
export default function( resolve ){
  console.log( resolve( process.argv[1] ) )
}
```

#### Alternatively, inject `require` and use `require.main.filename`:

##### main.js:

```js
import( "module.mjs" )
  .then( r => r.default( require ) )
```

or

```js
async ()=>{
  await import( "module.mjs" )
    .default( require )
}
```

##### module.mjs

```js
export default function( require ){
  console.log( require.main.filename )
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I ran into a similar issue while working with NodeJS. To resolve it I did
`process.cwd()`

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.